# Comparing two objects for matching values and pushing any non matching values to separate array, keep getting several duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays of objects that I'm comparing using the value group(first array) and groupName(second array). I push all matching groups to one array called `matching`, and all non matching objects I push to another array called `nonMatching`.

The function to get matching seems to work fine, only adding the matching elements. The problem lies with the find non matching function. I've been testing with a mock data set for the first array and it only contains 7 items, yet when I check the nonMatching array after running my function I have 26 items total, most of which are duplicates.

I'm really not sure where I'm going wrong and why the matching logic works but the nonMatching doesn't.

arr1:

```
[
  {
    "group": "uncategorized"
  },
  {
    "group": "bla blah"
  },
  {
    "group": "options and cool sheet"
  },
  {
    "group": "baz"
  },
  {
    "group": "foo"
  },
  {
    "group": "bar"
  },
  {
    "group": "null"
  }
]
```

arr2:

```
[
  {
      "groupName": "maintenance and parts",
      "groupType": "video"
  },
  {
      "groupName": "loser product",
      "groupType": "list"
  },
  {
      "groupName": "options and cool sheet",
      "groupType": "list"
  },
  {
      "groupName": "uncategorized",
      "groupType": "list"
  }
]
```

Functions:

```
function isEqual(object1, object2) {
  return object1.group === object2.groupName; // returns boolean
}

const matchingGroups = []
const nonMatchingGroups = []

let findMatching = arr1.map(group => {
  arr2.map(config => {
    if(group.group === config.groupName){
      matchingGroups.push(group)
    }
  })
})

let findNonMatching = arr1.map(group => {
  arr2.map(config => {
    if(!isEqual(group, config)){
      nonMatchingGroups.push(group)
    } else {
      return null
    }
  })
})

console.log('matchingGroups', matchingGroups) // returns array[2]
console.log('nonMatchingGroups', nonMatchingGroups) // returns array[26]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you're using the map and calculating if the `group` is equal to `config` for each and every element in the `arr2`.

You just need to find if the object exists in other or not. If the object doesn't exist then push the `group` to `findNonMatching` array.
You can use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for this.

```js
const arr1 = [
  {
    group: "uncategorized",
  },
  {
    group: "bla blah",
  },
  {
    group: "options and cool sheet",
  },
  {
    group: "baz",
  },
  {
    group: "foo",
  },
  {
    group: "bar",
  },
  {
    group: "null",
  },
];

const arr2 = [
  {
    groupName: "maintenance and parts",
    groupType: "video",
  },
  {
    groupName: "loser product",
    groupType: "list",
  },
  {
    groupName: "options and cool sheet",
    groupType: "list",
  },
  {
    groupName: "uncategorized",
    groupType: "list",
  },
];

function isEqual(object1, object2) {
  return object1.group === object2.groupName; // returns boolean
}

const matchingGroups = [];
const nonMatchingGroups = [];

let findMatching = arr1.map((group) => {
  arr2.map((config) => {
    if (group.group === config.groupName) {
      matchingGroups.push(group);
    }
  });
});

let findNonMatching = arr1.map((group) => {
  const objExist = arr2.find((config) => isEqual(group, config));
  if (!objExist) {
    nonMatchingGroups.push(group);
  }
});

console.log("matchingGroups", matchingGroups); // returns array[2]
console.log("nonMatchingGroups", nonMatchingGroups); // returns array[26]
```

FYI, You don't need to iterate twice to get this result. The same result can be easily achieved using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const arr1 = [
  {
    group: "uncategorized",
  },
  {
    group: "bla blah",
  },
  {
    group: "options and cool sheet",
  },
  {
    group: "baz",
  },
  {
    group: "foo",
  },
  {
    group: "bar",
  },
  {
    group: "null",
  },
];

const arr2 = [
  {
    groupName: "maintenance and parts",
    groupType: "video",
  },
  {
    groupName: "loser product",
    groupType: "list",
  },
  {
    groupName: "options and cool sheet",
    groupType: "list",
  },
  {
    groupName: "uncategorized",
    groupType: "list",
  },
];

function isEqual(object1, object2) {
  return object1.group === object2.groupName; // returns boolean
}

const result = arr1.reduce(
  (acc, group) => {
    const objExist = arr2.find((config) => isEqual(group, config));
    if (objExist) acc[0].push(group);
    else acc[1].push(group);
    return acc;
  },
  [[], []]
);

const matchingGroups = result[0];
const nonMatchingGroups = result[1];

console.log(matchingGroups);
console.log(nonMatchingGroups);
```